# Azure Continuous deployment failed with Github when deploying an Angular 2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, github, continuous-deployment

I am completely new to Azure and Angular2.

**The Objective**

Setup Azure Continuous deployment with GitHub.

**The Problem**

Azure is picking up commits to the main branch on the repository. So this part is OK. However, the deployment is failed due to a build error.

Here is the Deployment Details:

[image]

And here is the complete Log:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\app.component.ts(1,41): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\app.component.ts(2,46): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis-form.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis-form.component.ts(2,22): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/common'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis.component.ts(1,33): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis.service.ts(1,48): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis.service.ts(2,55): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis.service.ts(4,26): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\crisis.service.ts(12,16): error TS2304: Build: Cannot find name 'Promise'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero-form.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero-form.component.ts(2,22): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/common'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero.component.ts(1,33): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero.service.ts(1,48): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero.service.ts(2,55): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero.service.ts(4,26): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\hero.ts(1,18): error TS1148: Build: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\main.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\main.ts(2,32): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'. [D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\LearnJS.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d33697b325b07b";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\51.50212.2079\bin\scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

It seems that the build host does not find angular modules. I understand these modules exist in the `./node_modules` directory which is NOT checked in to my repository. I do have a `package.json` file in the repository, which looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.4",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5"
  }
}
```

**The Question**

What do I need to do to get Azure to pull these node.js modules when deploying the site?

Should I just check in my node_modules directory? But it seems to be against [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459475/should-i-check-in-node-modules-to-git-when-creating-a-node-js-app-on-heroku?lq=1).

**Things I have tried**

I installed Azure Command Line Interface and tried to run this command as suggested by [this post](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/dbaskin/deploying-an-es6-jspm-nodejs-application-to-azure).

```
azure site deploymentscript --node
```

But I got this error[image]

**Update 2016-02-18:**

Rerun the `azure site deploymentscript --node` command, which generates two files: `.deployment` and `deploy.cmd`. Committed both file into the main branch. Looking closely on the first line of the log, azure runs a `deploy.cmd` from this directory

```
D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd
```

Do I need to create a directory `deployments\tools` in my project or did I put the `deploy.cmd` at the wrong place?  I still got the same build error.

Partial log file AFTER checking two deployment files.

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
D:\home\site\repository\LearnJS\LearnJS.Web\app\app.component.ts(1,41): error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
```

Here is the deploy.cmd file:

```
    @if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 1.0.6
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
goto Deployment

:: Utility Functions
:: -----------------

:SelectNodeVersion

IF DEFINED KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD (
  :: The following are done only on Windows Azure Websites environment
  call %KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NODE_EXE=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NPM_JS_PATH=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED NODE_EXE (
    SET NODE_EXE=node
  )

  SET NPM_CMD="!NODE_EXE!" "!NPM_JS_PATH!"
) ELSE (
  SET NPM_CMD=npm
  SET NODE_EXE=node
)

goto :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

:: 1. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

:: 2. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

:: 3. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: Post deployment stub
IF DEFINED POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION call "%POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION%"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

Comment: Are you using ASPNet 5/Core 1.0?

Comment: I did started as an empty ASP Net project but the client is built with pure TypeScript and Angular 2 (beta 0). I attached my *.csproj to the question. I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 5

Comment: Is your app a pure client one? No .Net code? Or is it a NodeJS app?

Comment: yes, it is pure client. No .Net code.

Comment: It looks as if Azure has no idea that you actually have a node app, but rather an ASP.NET app, because I don't see in the logs any attempts whatsoever to run `npm install`

Comment: This might be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/14/windows-azure-websites-node-js.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, I think your needs was creating a static web project with TypeScript and Angular 2, then deploying the static website into Azure WebApp with Continuous Deployment via GitHub.

The simple way is creating a static web project in VS with nodejs tools, then only developing for these static web HTML page with js files compiled from ts files, then commit them to your created GitHub respository, and set up the continuous deployment from GitHub for Azure WebApp on Azure portal.

So I think you can try to refer to the other answered SO thread  [Deploying Hexo on Azure.. not sure what i'm missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875273/deploying-hexo-on-azure-not-sure-what-im-missing) to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment script for Node works, the problem is that you are using it on your harddrive root in a Non-Administrative Command Prompt.

Either open the Command Prompt with Administrative rights or run it on a folder where your user has write permission (maybe in your Documents folder).

[image: nodejs deployment script generation]

Add the generated files to your Web app folder. You don't need to create a VS .csproj, since it's a client-only application.

Typescript is among your 'devDependencies', that means that it's running on your Development Environment, it should be compiling the .ts files into .js files. You should push those compiled .js files to your repo and reference them in your pages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I committed the two generated files *.deployment and deploy.cmd file into the repository. But azure still thinks it as a .Net Web application, probably because I created a ASP. NET project in the first place. I still ended up with the build errors. Please see my updates for details.

Comment: The deploy.cmd and .deployment files need to be on the Root of the repo. Remove the .csproj file, it may lead Kudu to think it's a .Net app :)